# Angular directive with array data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a directive

```
app.directive('projects', ['projectServices',
    function(projectServices) {
        var projectController = function() {
            var proj = this

            projectServices.getProjects()
                .success(function(result) {
                    proj.projects = result.data

                    proj.projects.map(function(project) {
                        project.showDetails = false
                    })
                })
                .error(function(err) {
                    console.log('error ' + err)
                })

            this.toggleProjectDetails = function(project) {
                project.showDetails = !project.showDetails
            }

        }

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/partials/project',
            controller: projectController,
            controllerAs: 'projectCtrl'
        }
    }
])
```

The template looks like this

```
div(ng-repeat='project in projectCtrl.projects')
p(style='margin-bottom:0px') {{project.title}}
span.italic {{project.start_date | date}} - {{project.end_date | date}}
p {{project.abstract}}
    a.btn-xs(style='color:black' ng-click='projectCtrl.toggleProjectDetails(project)')
        i.fa.fa-angle-double-down
p(ng-show='{{project.showDetails}}') {{project.details}}
```

The projects look like this:

```
[{
"title" : "Project Title",
"abstract" : "Short abstract to show what you've done",
"details" : "Lorem impusm bla bla bla",
"start_date" : ISODate("2014-07-02T11:07:34.000Z"),
"end_date" : ISODate("2014-07-02T11:07:34.000Z"),
"links" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "link name",
        "url" : "www.google.com"
    }
   ]         
},...]
```

My problem is, that when I call the `toggleProjectDetails` the function is executed, but the  respective portion of the page is not rendered again. It's like the `ng-show` is not re-executed.

What am I missing here?

Here is a [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/udZcuSBPRtr0pMwyhwWm).

Comment: can you please add a plunker. that will be better here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it after a lot of debugging using your plunker. Finally started to change the project.details in the toggle method, which worked. Then found the ng-show bug.

The ng-show should not have the {{}}. So instead of

```
p(ng-show='{{project.showDetails}}') {{project.details}}
```

use

```
p(ng-show='project.showDetails') {{project.details}}
```

and done.

Comment: could you be more specific please? I don't know how to use the $apply() function.

Comment: Changed my answer. I used link instead of controller. $scope should be there as argument.

Comment: How do I change my template, as now I don't have any controller and nothing gets rendered.

Comment: Changed again to your old one. The projectController should have the $scope as argument, which can be used in toggleProjectDetails.

Comment: I am still having trouble. I've added a plucker, you might want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue, in short I created a controller for the array, that handled the service and I added a controller for each element in the array. My code looks like this:

Controller and the directive that holds the projects (my array returned from the server):

```
app.directive('projects', ['projectServices',
    function(projectServices) {
        var projectController = function($scope) {

            projectServices.getProjects()
                .success(function(result) {
                    $scope.projects = result.data
                })
                .error(function(err) {
                    console.log('error ' + err)
                })
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/partials/project',
            controller: projectController,
            controllerAs: 'ProjectListController'
        }
    }
])
```

The controller for each project:

```
app.controller("projectController", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
        $scope.project.shDetails = false;

        $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
            $scope.project.shDetails = !$scope.project.shDetails
        };

        $scope.showDetails = function() {
            return $scope.project.shDetails
        }
    }
])
```

and my modified template:

```
div(ng-controller="projectController" ng-repeat='project in projects')
    p(style='margin-bottom:0px') {{project.title}}
    span.italic {{project.start_date | date}} - {{project.end_date | date}}
    p {{project.abstract}}
    a.btn(style='color:black' ng-click='toggleDetails()') 
        i.fa.fa-angle-double-down
    p(ng-show='showDetails()') {{project.details}}
```